How to pass a 'Pubkey' as an expected type in the expected schema in borsh-python?
I am trying to deserialize the following hexidecimal string:

"e445a52e51cb9a1dbddb7fd34ee661eecf5078301148ff160d7d39c2eb39bd8a65336260014e92375510898fccc8b08f00d2496b000000005b49b52a3d3700000118fd4318e5c5d0ebafd594a987aa6bd95ced29e4b785c4ef9de66783fc08cdc54a1a656600000000007e6d6707000000a5c6221da698030000d2496b00000000a52e10d1149a0200"

My approach has been to use Pythons borsh library (https://pypi.org/project/borsh-python/), which works fine. However, a problem I am facing is I dont know how to pass a 'Pubkey' as an expected type in the expected schema.
Here is my current code trying to deserialize the following hexidecimal string:

"e445a52e51cb9a1dbddb7fd34ee661eecf5078301148ff160d7d39c2eb39bd8a65336260014e92375510898fccc8b08f00d2496b000000005b49b52a3d3700000118fd4318e5c5d0ebafd594a987aa6bd95ced29e4b785c4ef9de66783fc08cdc54a1a656600000000007e6d6707000000a5c6221da698030000d2496b00000000a52e10d1149a0200"

import borsh
from borsh import types
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey


# Define the schema for the dictionary
example_dict_schema = borsh.schema({
    'idk': types.u64,
    'mint': Pubkey,
    'solAmount': types.u64,
    'tokenAmount': types.u64,
    'isBuy': types.u8,
    'user': Pubkey,
    'timestamp': types.i64,
    'virtualSolReserves': types.u64,
    'virtualTokenReserves': types.u64
})

serialized_bytes = bytes.fromhex('e445a52e51cb9a1dbddb7fd34ee661eecf5078301148ff160d7d39c2eb39bd8a65336260014e92375510898fccc8b08f00d2496b000000005b49b52a3d3700000118fd4318e5c5d0ebafd594a987aa6bd95ced29e4b785c4ef9de66783fc08cdc54a1a656600000000007e6d6707000000a5c6221da698030000d2496b00000000a52e10d1149a0200')

deserialized_data = borsh.deserialize(example_dict_schema, serialized_bytes)

print(deserialized_data)

My main problem is: TypeError: value '<class 'solders.pubkey.Pubkey'>' is not a valid Borsh type. I understand Pubkey is a valid Borsh type, but do not know how else to tell borsh to handle 'publicKey' and 'user' fields appropriately.
Here is the expected output:
{
  "mint": {
    "type": "publicKey",
    "data": "ExGZYPhHkhQ4jCbYPicCZz89tEmtVKiS6j9MhSqypump"
  },
  "solAmount": {
    "type": "u64",
    "data": "1800000000"
  },
  "tokenAmount": {
    "type": "u64",
    "data": "60735849056603"
  },
  "isBuy": {
    "type": "bool",
    "data": true
  },
  "user": {
    "type": "publicKey",
    "data": "2gYmikFDQno2o7shxA6CgDF5AVM6Px6DpHRNc6RNMiDS"
  },
  "timestamp": {
    "type": "i64",
    "data": "1717901898"
  },
  "virtualSolReserves": {
    "type": "u64",
    "data": "31800000000"
  },
  "virtualTokenReserves": {
    "type": "u64",
    "data": "1012264150943397"
  }
}

ACTUAL OUTPUT
TypeError: value '<class 'solders.pubkey.Pubkey'>' is not a valid Borsh type
This is obviously not what I want. Is there another type value I should be using, instead of simply putting 'Pubkey'? Here are the lsit of borsh accepted types (https://borsh.io/ - under specification tab).
Or
Should I be trying to construct a new borsh type manually? If this is the case, how would I go about creating a new borsh type of a Pubkey?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It looks like the question is no longer relevant, but here is the answer for those who are interested, since I struggled myself with this for a long time!
For pubkeys just use fixed array with u8 type and 32 bytes length:
borsh.types.fixed_array(_type=borsh.types.u8, length=32)

Then after successfull deserialize it will look like this (mint for example):
deserialized["mint"] >>> [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]

And then just use this code to convert mint array into PubKey:
pubkey_bytes = bytes(deserialized["mint"])
pubkey = Pubkey.from_bytes(pubkey_bytes)

